# how to update the root/parent node text

Tags: vb6, treeview

im newbie to vb6 and i dont know how can i update the root/parent node when variable "childCount" is change?

thanks

example :

```
Dim nodx As Node
dim childCount as integer

childCount = 0

Set TreeView1.ImageList = ImageList1

'Add root Node
Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(, , "Root", "Root Node have " & childCount & " child" ,"Closed")

'Expand root node so we can see what's under it
nodx.ExpandedImage = "Open"
nodx.Expanded = True

'Create a child node under the root node
Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child1", "Child node 1", "Closed")

childCount =childCount + 1
'Expand this node so we can see what's under it
nodx.ExpandedImage = "Open"
nodx.Expanded = True

'Create several more children
Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child2", "Child node 2", "Leaf")

childCount =childCount + 1

Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child3", "Child node 3", "Leaf")

childCount =childCount + 1

Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child4", "Child node 4", "Leaf")

childCount =childCount + 1

Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child5", "Child node 5", "Leaf")

childCount =childCount + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are updating the root node (the first node), you already know the index number is 1, so your task is especially easy.

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Item(1).Text = "Root Node have " & CStr(childCount)
```

You can also update the root of the new node. In your sample it is the same as Index 1.

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Item(TreeView1.Nodes.Count).Root.Text = "Root Node have " & CStr(childCount)
```

Try pausing the execution and in the **Immediate Window** play with the different properties of the control.

Comment: i found the solution thanks to @Beaner for his idea, what i do is:                                                                   Dim nodx As Node

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution thanks to @Beaner for his idea, what i do is:

```
Dim nodx As Node
Dim nodChild As Node
dim childCount as integer 

Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(, , "Root", "Root Node have " & childCount & " child" ,"Closed")  

'Expand root node so we can see what's under it 
nodx.ExpandedImage = "Open" 
nodx.Expanded = True  

'Create a child node under the root node 
Set nodChild = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child1", "Child node 1", "Closed")  childCount =childCount + 1 

'Expand this node so we can see what's under it nodx.ExpandedImage = "Open" nodx.Expanded = True  
'Create several more children 
Set nodChild = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child2", "Child node 2", "Leaf")  childCount =childCount + 1  

Set nodChild = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child3", "Child node 3", "Leaf")  childCount =childCount + 1  

Set nodChild = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child4", "Child node 4", "Leaf")  childCount =childCount + 1  

Set nodChild = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root", tvwChild, "Child5", "Child node 5", "Leaf")  childCount =childCount + 1 

nodx.Text = "Root Node have " & childCount & " child"
```

Comment: You don't need `nodx` variable because `TreeView1.Nodes(1)` is the root.